# Select count(field) and select field, is that count on the same lines?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I make a `COUNT` on the fields of `mytable` with a `LIMIT` parameter,

```
SELECT COUNT(field1), COUNT(field2)
FROM mytable
LIMIT 10000
```

And if I select their fields

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM mytable
LIMIT 10000
```

Are there two requests `select` and `count` on the same 10000 lines ?

Because I can add an `ORDER BY` clause to the second request, but for a `COUNT` request it is not possible.

Thanks for help

Comment: Count is evaluated before LIMIT. That means that PostgreSQL evaluates all of `mytable` for the COUNT function, and the result of the aggregate function is limited to 10000. Basically this LIMIT is useless in this query. Run it on a table with 10001 rows and you will see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't count on it, without an `ORDER BY` clause to specify the wanted order, there are no guarantees !

Just wrap the first query with another select :

```
SELECT COUNT(field1),count(field2) 
FROM(SELECT field1,field2
     FROM mytable
     ORDER BY Order_Column
     LIMIT 10000) t

SELECT field1, field2
FROM mytable
ORDER BY Order_Column
LIMIT 10000
```

These queries will process the same rows

Comment: Thanks. Just add an alias to the subquery

Comment: Unless `Order_Column` is unique there's no guarantee that the same rows are returned :)

Comment: Yea, didn't think about that, will probably process **most** of the same rows:) , though he accepted the answer so I assume it is unique @dnoeth

Comment: @Macbernie Just for fun, yet another solution without subquery: `SELECT COUNT(field1) OVER foo, COUNT(field2) OVER foo FROM mytable WINDOW foo AS (ORDER BY <order fields> ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 9999 FOLLOWING) LIMIT 1`

Comment: And what about performances @Abelisto ? Is your request better ?

Comment: @Macbernie I test it on simple table with 3 integer field (indexes on each, table analyzes) and 10,000,000 rows. It is almost same for small limits (1000-10000) but sagi's solution much faster for large limits (100000 and more). So, lets say, the my solution is an answer to your remark about possibility of combining 'order by' and `count` in the one query :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless and until you add `order by` to your query, you cannot say anything about the order of the rows returned. You can add `order by` to a nested query for the `select count(...)` to solve this problem. Essentially, the second query becomes the nested query for your `select count(...)`

```
-- Second query
SELECT field1, field2
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ... LIMIT 10000

-- First query
SELECT COUNT(field1), COUNT(field2) FROM (
    SELECT field1, field2
    FROM mytable
    ORDER BY ... LIMIT 10000
}
```